# How do you track items (not just code) that need to moved to the next stage after development?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, webforms

We are a team of about 10 people and growing rapidly. We are developing in ASP.Net webforms along with Oracle and TFS 2010. We are using TFS for source control and recently started using it for work items as our team has grown 200% in the last 6months.

It seems straight forward to 'set' work item as ready for testing after it is done in development. What I am trying to figure out is how can I let the person(s) know what else had changed besides what is checked into TFS. 99% of the time this will be database related. I was hoping for something inside TFS so that it could be queryable. As in give me all item that are tagged as 'ready for test' but I open for anything!

While we do manage the server software and production pushes we are in a very large enterprise company so something's like server OS are out of our control.

Comment: Can you not just use the in-built query system in TFS, WorkItems > New Query > add project and state of "ready for test"

Comment: Why not use database projects, which are checked into TFS?

Comment: @sa_ddam231 - That works fine for code, but is there a better way besides saying table XXX was updated?

Comment: @john - Will check into that, this is an old and VERY large Oracle database so something tells me this is not going to be easy.

Answer (score 0):

You could get your database changes stored as a query (ideally encapsulated in a transaction with a rollback statement on error).